# Getting started with exact target

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, fuel

I have gone through API getting started exact target api https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api/

But I am having few questions

1. Can Mass Email functionality be done using exact target like I want to add a button on campaign,Which will pick email address of campaign members and an email will be sent to all campaign members.
2. From where should I start?
3. Can I create a account on exact target. Which will be free?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Send via the Send ExactTarget email link on a Campaign](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v2_non_enterprise_2_0/exacttarget_integration_with_salesforce_user_guide/sending_emails/sending_an_email_cmpn2/#section_1) in the exact target help. It covers how you can easily use an existing button to get the functionality you described.

To get a trial account, try the form in the [Marketing Cloud Demo](https://www.exacttarget.com/request-a-demo).